# Why and when should a goto be used in C / C++?

Tags: c++, c, goto

I know lots of questions about why not use `goto`, why `goto` is bad practice, why `goto` was create by devil, why the fingers of those who type `goto` should be ripped off, etc...

And in [many answers to this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18507518/what-are-some-better-ways-to-avoid-the-do-while0-hack-in-c) , [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful/), and even at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto#Criticism_and_decline) it's possible to find reasons pro / against `goto`.

Even Stackoverflow has a `goto` tag :)

But, obviously, `goto` is accepted as a valid command, otherwise your compiler / interpreter wouldn't know what to do with it. Even in C / C++ it's possible to use `goto`, and that language even has a formal, ISO specification.

So, probably, there should be some case where only by using `goto` it's possible to accomplish some task. Then, why and when should a `goto` be used in C / C++ ?

*Edit:*

Just to make sure:

1 - this question doesn't require debate. It should be answerable: giving one or more cases where `goto` is the only solution, or stating `no, it's always possible to avoid a goto`. Of course, I'm not the only who can decide whether it should be closed or not, but I don't think that "too broad, asks for debate, etc" are reasons to close it.

2 - There might be some cases where `goto` make the code cleaner, faster, etc. I don't want those. I want to know if there exists one case where `goto` is the only solution (no, it's not a dup of that "give good examples of goto" question)

3 - I'll accept any downvote, with a smile on my face, if the downvote is justified. But I'm pretty sure that this question has an answer and has done previous research about the subject. Downvoting simple because those 4-letters taboo word that starts with a "G" was used... sorry...

Comment: This question is too opinionated for the Q/A format of Stack Overflow. The answer is mostly a matter of style, and depends very much on the exact situation.

Comment: no... I don't want an opinion. I want a concrete case where only goto could be used to solve some situation. I don't want opinions about speed, make-your-code-more-obscure...

Comment: Then no. There is no case where `goto` is the *only* option. You can do any branching task using `if`, `for` and `switch`, but that can result in less readable code in some very rare cases.

Comment: @Dave would you mind making that an answer?

Comment: Generated code sometimes needs goto. The rest can live without.

Comment: Any language that is Turing complete can do 'anything'.  It's a matter of convenience and overall utility that 'extra' operations are added to a language.

Comment: C++: never, C: rarely

Comment: @Hasturkun hum... that question shows many good examples where you can use a goto. But doesn't answer my existential doubt: is there a case where goto must be used, because it's the only solution ?

Comment: @woliveirajr No, there isn't. `goto` might be better than something else in some situations, but it's never the only choice.

Comment: @woliveirajr - Sorry your question got marked as a dupe. It is NOT a dupe (or at least not a dupe of the one indicated).  You're asking for a scenario where `goto` is the _only_ possible solution, which is a completely different question than where `goto` is a _good_ solution.

Comment: Regarding your updated comments, let's be honest: whatever the intent of the question, you are *going* to get mostly opinion-based answers, which is why I voted to close it as too broad (my vote got drawn in to the dupe votes but, nevermind). You have an answer from several sources now: No. There is no situation. The best you can hope for now is that every possibility is suggested and shot-down with counterexamples, which is not constructive.

Comment: @Dave I can expect that this questions gets one example (I doubt) or get a good answer showing some real examples where a code with goto can be changed to a code without goto, and then it's the answer... Agree with you, people can debate anything, of course, but it's not my question fault

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no circumstance under which a `goto` is strictly necessary: you can *always* avoid it if you really want to, but to do that for purely idealogical reasons is a mistake.

For example, a friend of mine wrote a wavelet transform function that had (something like) 15 nested loops. In the event of an error in those loops, he had a `goto` to a cleanup block just before the function's `return` statement. To achieve the same effect *without* a goto would have involved setting a flag and testing it at every loop level, which would have made his code far less readable. In these circumstances, `goto` was the right choice.

Comment: Tell your friend that 15 nested loops is too many… by about 13.

Comment: Maybe that wasn't obvious to him 17 years ago.

Comment: My point is that whether goto was the right choice in that situation or not is irrelevant: the situation itself was bad. Besides, this is an example of when `goto` might be the better option. The question is looking for cases where it is the *only* option.

Comment: Those cases don't exist, since the language is Turing complete without a `goto` construct. Therefore, the only reasonable answer, IMHO, is to state this fact and give an example of where it is preferable, even if it can be avoided, which is exactly what I did. If your point was related to the substantive issue in question, rather than a snipe at an irrelevant detail, your comment did not convey that very well.

Comment: See my comments on the main question's comment thread if you want my full opinion. If you update your answer with the turing completeness argument (and I'd suggest removing the irrelevant example of it being preferable in a particular situation), I'd have no issue with it.

Comment: I'm happy with my answer as it is, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The latest MISRA standard now allows gotos.

A good example where gotos make sense is when you have a large routine with a lot of exits points.  You can have many return statements (not good) convolute the code with 'structured programming' conditionals (also not good) or a "goto Done;  which sends the program to a set of ending statements before returning.

The MISRA standard basically allows gotos for these sort of circumstances.  I think 'only downward' is one of their criteria.

Comment: I fail to see how goto is better than multiple return statements.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177276/c-c-conditional-return-statements/17177315#17177315

Comment: @jrok: typically when you have a chunk of clean up code that would otherwise be duplicated if you used multiple returns.

Comment: @PaulR Ok, I can imagine that in C. But in C++ RAII should be better for that, no? And when there's nothing to clean up, multiple return statements aren't neccesarily bad.

Comment: You invoke MISRA like it's some sort of bible that controls all programming.

Comment: There's a lot of things I don't like about MISRA.  But it is a standard which tries to explain the rationale behind the decisions.  I found it significant that they backed off banning gotos (and 'break', except for use in switch, and 'continue') compared with their earlier standard.  MISRA is a C standard, so it's particular to C and not (I don't think) C++.

Comment: @jrok: yes, I was talking about C as the context here is MISRA. C++ is a different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 5):

The only reason I use a goto is when it is for an error return condition from a function that needs some common cleanup. The target of the goto is near the end of the function and the "normal" return returns before the label.

Comment: Yes!  If you have any final processing to do before returning, you can put that all in one place.  A number of 'goto Done' s in the code is not confusing or spaghettish, as it is clear what is going on.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example where only goto will work:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/245801/193848

Basically if you have multiple nested `for` loops, the only way to break out of all the loops from an inner loop is with a `goto` statement (since unlike some other languages the C `break` keyword doesn't support a parameter for the number of nesting levels to break out).

Comment: Even this doesn't *require* goto. You can also use a variable as a marker that the loop is over, and break out of each level individually. `goto` simply provides a more readable and potentially faster (though I'd doubt it with modern compilers) option. Using a small function and `return` (as suggested in the comments on that answer) is also a good option which will compile to be almost identical to using a `goto`.

Comment: Yes, functionally that may work, but I think you missed the point.  If you want to break out of all the loops _immediately_ then only `goto` will work.  In your example you're adding a variable comparison check at every level of nesting, which isn't the same as breaking out immediately.

Comment: The second option (a separate function with a return) *will* break out immediately. I agree that in some cases a `goto` is more appropriate, but you cannot possibly claim it is the *only* way.

Comment: I am absolutely claiming it is the _only_ way to _immediately_ break out of nested `for` loops and continue with subsequent code in that function.  I'm not saying that's the best practice and I'm not saying the loops etc couldn't be rewritten to accomplish the goal in another way.  I'm saying it's the only way to accomplish that particular goal without rewriting the surrounding code.

Comment: Of course, by that standard you could argue that *all* uses of `goto` are cases "where only `goto` will work", because `goto` is the *only* way to *immediately* jump to an arbitrarily-specified place in the function. To remove `goto` from a function always involves rewriting the surrounding code.